# How make array insert array json in web service C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, web-services

How can I create a JsonArray with a child data object array? I am using Web service and C#.

I want the result of the JsonArray to look like the following:

```
[{
    "name": "Deadpool",
    "url": {
        "small": "http://api.android.info/images/small/deadpool.jpg",
        "medium": "http://api.android.info/images/medium/deadpool.jpg",
        "large": "http://api.android.info/images/large/deadpool.jpg"
    },
    "time": "February 12, 2016"
},
{
    "name": "The Jungle Book",
    "url": {
        "small": "http://api.android.info/images/small/book.jpg",
        "medium": "http://api.android.info/images/medium/book.jpg",
        "large": "http://api.android.info/images/large/book.jpg"
    },
    "time": "April 15, 2016"
},
{
    "name": "X-Men: Apocalypse",
    "url": {
        "small": "http://api.android.info/images/small/xmen.jpg",
        "medium": "http://api.android.info/images/medium/xmen.jpg",
        "large": "http://api.android.info/images/large/xmen.jpg"
    },
    "time": "May 27, 2016"
}]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You current question is not that clear. Can you add some more details to your questions?

Comment: How do you access to your data ? from a database ? Do you use linq ?

Comment: I think what you want is how to create your class structure to convert your data in to a jsonarray like your example. Is this is what you expecting

Comment: @Seminda yes thats it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the models that can output the given data. You need a `MovieModel`, a movie can have multiple image sizes and urls stored, we use a dictionary for this.

**UPDATED**

**MovieModel.cs**

```
public class MovieModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Url { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to install `Newtonsoft.Json` from Nuget packages. Then import it.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Initialize the model and convert to Json using `SerializeObject()` method.

```
var movieList = new List<MovieModel>
{ 
    new MovieModel
    {
        MovieName = "Deadpool",
        Time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("t"),
        Url = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "small", "http://api.android.info/images/small/deadpool.jpg" },
            { "medium", "http://api.android.info/images/medium/deadpool.jpg" }
        }
    }
    // .. add more movies .. //
};

// convert to camelcase and set indentation
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    movieList,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    }
);

// testing output on console
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

In a real application, you would create Movie instances by getting data from a database, not initializing it for yourself as used in this example.

Comment: it works mr.abdul, but in result "url" : [{ "small" : "http.....", "medium" : "http....." }]
i dont want  to put "[" in list data "url"

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Square brackets in Json means it's an array of items, if you remove it, consuming applications might have trouble deserializing back to an object.

Comment: because in tutorial json is that, so i want to create like that,,
you can check this url : api.androidhive.info/json/glide.json  ..